# I need the character (square form) which entirely filled the charactere area and there is no spaces between two of these characters

Tags: vba, excel, character-encoding, character, special-characters

> I need the square-symbolized character have the square shape that fills entire the character's area, (black).

**Example:** There where the character with (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + 196) ASCII code which is a line that horizontally filled the width of the character's space:

Here is 5 character of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 196: ─────

So there is no space between characters.

> I need this form for a squared character that fills the width and height of the characters space.

Regards.

Comment: I Updated to focus what I needed.

Comment: Still not clear i'm afraid. I thought perhaps you wanted a button image that has a black fill but then the line and spacing entered the equation. Are you trying to size the button as well? Clearer explanation and, as mentioned above, some code, would help.

Comment: I need a character. I'm looking for a character. A character and it's ASCII code to type with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(`code`). The character with the square shape which that fills entire space of the characters so when we type some number of this character, there where no space with them, same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+196; Example: 3 number of this character: ───

Comment: Thank you for updating your post.  I removed my Close flag and posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Three Full block characters**

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = String(3, ChrW(&H2588))`

**Horizontal Line (3 characters)**

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = String(3, ChrW(&H2500))`
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4") = String(3, ChrW(&H25AC))`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you use the charmap tool as proposed by @Thomas-Inzina +) you can group into several *Unicode* subcategories and get the necessary hexadecimal code for the `ChrW` function (prefixed with `&H`).

Answer (score 2):

The character is called the En Dash and it's code is 150.  The way that I determined this is by using the Symbol Dialog to insert the it into a cell and then in the Immediate Window I used `?Asc(ActiveCell.Value)` to get its Character Code.  `Chr(150)` will reproduce the character and the String function can be used to repeat the it (e.g. `String(5, 150)` returns ───── ).

[image: Symbol Dialog]

Comment: Regards. The character that I needed, has similarity and difference with one you advised. I need the character with squared-symbolized which it's height been same as the `Chr(150)`'s width too.

Comment: `String(5,110)` will print 5 black squares.  You best bet is to bring up the Symbol Dialog and try to find it i the list.  You might end up having to change the Font.

Comment: It looks like you don't want any breaks just a solid black line.  Sorry, I never seen this.